# How to write a post with Google+ Domain APIs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus

I'm writing an application on google appengine and python, that interacts with the social network Google+, in particular I need to use the Google+ Domains API for writing a post on Google+.
I have tried the following code:

```
class Oauth2Handler(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
        'client_secret.json',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login '
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me '
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email '
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write'
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback'
    )

    # Step1 del protocollo oauth2
    if not self.request.get('code'):
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

    # Step2 del protocollo oauth2
    else:
        auth_code = self.request.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        http = httplib2.Http(cache=memcache)
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(http=http)

        gplus_service = build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http_auth)
        gplus_service.activities().insert(
        userId='me',
        body={
            'object': {
            'originalContent': 'Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays'
            },
            'access': {
                'items': [{
                'type': 'domain'
                }],
                'domainRestricted': True
            }
        }).execute(http=http_auth)
```

This code generates the exception:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

I have read in this [document](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation) that I must insert the scopes plus.me and stream.write in my Google Apps domain control panel, but I don't have a Google for work account.
How should I do for solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: If you don't have a Google for Work account you can't use the Domains API.

Comment: there is no other method for sharing a post on google plus?

Comment: Not in an automated way. It's recommended to use the [share button or share link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link).